# datetime/day finance/day conflict

Tags: matlab, datetime

I am trying to use the `day` function in `datetime` as

```
day(dateserial, 'dayofyear')
```

instead the function `day` from finance package is called giving me day of month because there is a day function with a similar signature.

I couldn't find in the documentation how to distinguish same function names. I find recommendations on the internet saying I should remove package from path but that's absurd as these are standard MATLAB packages.

example:

```
day(now,'dayofyear')

Warning: Unless the first input argument is a date character vector, all subsequent arguments will be ignored. 
 In datevec (line 67)

 In day (line 39) 

ans =

23
```

It seems `date` and `datetime` are not compatible.

Comment: They have different syntax right? That's how you *should* distinguish them. Using a certain syntax will trigger MATLAB to the correct function.

Comment: @Adriaan no unfortunately there is another function with two parameters. It doesn't. This is MATLAB 2016b, by the way.

Comment: Include inputs to demonstrate the problem.  It works fine for me.  Pretty sure `dayofyear` is not a valid date format to describe a serial date.

Comment: @Matt I added. It seems it doesn't like serial dates.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc you're incorrect there, the functions *do* have a different input. I agree that it's obfuscated and obtruse from TMW to call two separate functions by the same name, but at least they are fully seperable by input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `day` in the finance toolbox take a serial date or character vector as an input.  For example:

```
day(datenum(now));
```

The function `day` that you want takes a datetime array as an input.

```
day(datetime(2017,02,23,01,06,00), 'dayofyear');

ans = 
    54
```

Matlab uses the input type to determine which function to use.

Comment: Great, so how can I get date of year from a serial date? The subtract beginning of year trick.

Comment: Chain them all together?  `day(datetime(datevec(now)), 'dayofyear')`  I'm sure there a many ways, just depends on how you want to do it.

Comment: OK. Thanks. They couldn't have made it more inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

Your input to `day()` needs to be a datetime (not a number). If it's a datetime then it will call the day() function/method that applies to datetimes.

```
dt = datetime( datevec(now) )
day(dt, 'dayofyear')
```